# System.Web.Mvc.dll added to webforms project

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've been working on a webforms application with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, .Net 4.6, and VB on a Windows 10 PC.  When I do a build and test my app, i'm now getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor".

After doing a compare of the Bin folder with a backup, I found there are 2 additional files: System.Web.Mvc.dll and System.Web.Mvc.xml.  Deleting these 2 files fixes the problem, but I have to do this every time I do a build or publish.

I've never used Razor or MVC.  I haven't made any major changes except for installing Visual Studio Update 3 about a week before the problem started.

I did a search for MVC in my project and found the 2 files listed in obj\Release\MyApplication.vbproj.FileListAbsolute.txt.  I tried removing them but they are added back when doing a build.  I Tried cleaning and building the project too.

Any suggestions on where to look for a solution?

Comment: Hi Tom, did you get any resolution to this problem? we are too experiencing the same problem.

Comment: No I haven't found a solution.  I plan to uninstall VS 2015 and then install VS 2017 to see if that fixes it.  I am using Telerik controls for asp.net ajax, but I doubt that's related.  Getting tired of deleting System.Web.Mvc.dll every time I do a build.

Comment: I finally resolved this.  I uninstalled VS 2015 and installed VS 2017, but that didn't fix it.  I went into Control Panel/Programs and Features and found MS Asp.net MVC 4 Runtime.  I uninstalled it and that fixed it.  Hope this helps someone.  Additional info, I'm developing on Win 10 with VB.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I am yet to verify it myself but I appreciate you shared something useful.

Comment: It's back.  A couple weeks ago I did a build and got the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor".  I uninstalled the MVC4 runtime again, but it was automatically installed again the next day.  I've uninstalled it a few times but it keeps coming back.  Now I need to find a way to prevent it from being installed automatically.